# Open a windows network diagnostic with a button?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Is it possible to open the windows network diagnostic from C# code (a button-click handler)? How can I do this?

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 3):

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144191.aspx). Here's an example:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
    "Rundll32.exe","ndfapi,NdfRunDllDiagnoseIncident");
```